# What is the best way to implement live video chat in codeigniter wep site?

Tags: codeigniter, videochat

Actually I tried this using webRTC. But most of the functionalities are not worked in that plugin. How do i do in codeigniter website? Plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look around and found this http://www.cometchat.com/codeigniter-chat give this ago.

Its good to search more on Google and YouTube. Or ask on http://forum.codeigniter.com/ There main new forum now.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3CB4877FA6E788B3

Check compatible versions.